# Gsub and regular expression

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a web page. The HTML source contains this text:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="John"/>
```

John is an example, the name may vary.
I am sure that og:title will appear only once in the text.
This is my code:

```
$browser.goto( url )
x = $browser.html.gsub( /^.*<meta property="og:title" content="(.+?)".>/m, '\1' )
```

I expected to find the name John in my variable x
The '\1' should give me the first part I put in the parenthesis, i.e. (.+?), i.e. John, right?
Also, I used a dot . to match a slash / , is there a better way?

Comment: So, you want value of `content` attribute in variable `x`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and how many tags are you working with? For anything beyond a trivial use, you should use a parser, because regex can break badly anytime the page changes.

Comment: Yes, Željko, I want that

Comment: Your code appears to be working for me. So are you just asking for a nicer way to do this or is the code not working for you? If the latter, what do you get for x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the value of `content`:

```
html = '<meta property="og:title" content="John"/>'
=> "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"John\"/>"
html[/property="og:title" content="([^"]+)"/, 1]
=> "John"
```

If you're not familiar with regex, `"([^"]+)"` might throw you. It means "from the first `"`, grab everything until the next `"`. In effect it means "grab everything inside the double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Using Watir API:

```
x = browser.meta.attribute_value "content"
```

I was not able to access the `meta` element using either `css` and `xpath`.

Comment: I am more interested in learning about regexp, so my ideal answer should show me what's wrong in what I did

Comment: It was wrong to use regex in the first place so Zeljko's answer should be accepted

Answer (score 1):

That code will return all of the HTML, with the matching code (which is everything between the start of the string up to and including the />) replaced by 'John'. So that comes down to "John", followed by the HTML that was after the /> of that meta property.

If you only want to extract the name, and that tag occurs only once, you can use something like:

```
@browser.html =~ /<meta property="og:title" content="(.+?)"/
x = $1
```